# Loading UI Calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, calendar

Hi I am trying to get UI Calendar to work. Everytime I go to the page I get following error trying to load scripts and nothing displays for calendar. Please let me know what is the problem

```
Error: controller.changeWatcher is not a function
.link@http://localhost:43267/bower_components/angular-ui-calendar/src/calendar.js:219:35
cloneAndAnnotateFn/<@http://localhost:43267/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8646:41

invokeLinkFn@http://localhost:43267/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8652:9
nodeLinkFn@http://localhost:43267/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8152:1
compositeLinkFn@http://localhost:43267/bower_components/angular/angular.js:7543:13
compositeLinkFn@http://localhost:43267/bower_components/angular/angular.js:7547:13
compositeLinkFn@http://localhost:43267/bower_components/angular/angular.js:7547:13
compositeLinkFn@http://localhost:43267/bower_components/angular/angular.js:7547:13
compositeLinkFn@http://localhost:43267/bower_components/angular/angular.js:7547:13
compositeLinkFn@http://localhost:43267/bower_components/angular/angular.js:7547:13
publicLinkFn@http://localhost:43267/bower_components/angular/angular.js:7418:30
$ViewDirectiveFill/<.compile/<@http://localhost:43267/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js:3905:9
invokeLinkFn@http://localhost:43267/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8652:9
nodeLinkFn@http://localhost:43267/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8152:1
compositeLinkFn@http://localhost:43267/bower_components/angular/angular.js:7543:13
publicLinkFn@http://localhost:43267/bower_components/angular/angular.js:7418:30
updateView@http://localhost:43267/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js:3839:23
$ViewDirective/directive.compile/</<@http://localhost:43267/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js:3801:11
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$broadcast@http://localhost:43267/bower_components/angular/angular.js:16167:15
transitionTo/$state.transition<@http://localhost:43267/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js:3218:11
processQueue@http://localhost:43267/bower_components/angular/angular.js:14569:28
scheduleProcessQueue/<@http://localhost:43267/bower_components/angular/angular.js:14585:27
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$eval@http://localhost:43267/bower_components/angular/angular.js:15848:16
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$digest@http://localhost:43267/bower_components/angular/angular.js:15659:15
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$apply@http://localhost:43267/bower_components/angular/angular.js:15953:13
done@http://localhost:43267/bower_components/angular/angular.js:10366:36
completeRequest@http://localhost:43267/bower_components/angular/angular.js:10538:7
requestLoaded@http://localhost:43267/bower_components/angular/angular.js:10479:1
```

Thank your for your help

Comment: can you post some code? its difficult to guess what's wrong without seeing the code

Answer (score 0):

Without any relevant code. All I can guess is that you are missing a library, causing angular to throw an error upon calling a function that doesn't exist in your code. If you post some more code I might be able to offer you a better answer